# Can Database Normalization occur from values

Tags: sql, database-design, entity-relationship, normalization

Say I want to normalize a table

```
itemID | itemDate | itemSource | type | color | size | material
 254    03/08/1988    toyCo      doll   null     16    plastic
 255    03/08/1988    toyCo      car    blue     null  plastic
 256    03/08/1988    toyCo      boat   purple   20    wood
```

Now the type field can only have 1 of 3 values. `doll, car, or boat`. Attributes of `color, size, and material` are functionally dependent on `type`. As you can see though, items of `type|doll` do not determine `color`. I do not know if this is a problem. But moving on.

`type(pk) | color | size | material` = table A
`itemID(pk) | itemDate | itemSource` = table B

We are now in 1nf. **My question is**, can the `type` key, along with its attributes, become based on the type keys' possible values?

`typeDoll(pk) | size | material` = table C
`typeCar(pk) | color| material` = table D
`typeBoat(pk) | color | size | material` table E

Comment: But then tables C, D, and E all become tables of one row, all with the same column structure and same functional dependence between columns. Why are you chasing up this tree? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: They wont be of one row. There can be many `dolls, cars, and boats`. `table C` can have many rows of dolls with different colors and materials. The reason I am chasing up this tree is: I want tables of pure data. If later I introduce columns of `foo, foo2, foo3, foo4` etc into `table A` but those columns are only useful to rows with `type` value `doll` then that means I can create `boat` and `car` rows that will have empty or null values for `foo, foo2, foo3, foo4`. I see this as wasteful. Am I correct?

Comment: Brain fart alert! You are correct of course. However they remain the same column structure with the same functional dependencies. I believe you are over generalizing. Since table B is a lookup table except for its own maintenance, it can easily be replaced by a view later if needed. Start with C,D, ad E as views on the base table B, and reverse this if necessary down the line.

Comment: I dont think its a overgeneralization. What I am tying to achieve is called polymorphism. It has great OOB uses. I would like to constrain one foreign key to many of possible table keys.

Comment: I still think you are trying to screw in a nail.

Comment: Well, the first obvious problem here is that you are trying to "normalize" on small subset of data. For example, `FD type -> color` means that all cars are blue, all boats are purple and all dolls are colourless. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking, but here's one approach to creating an exclusive arc in SQL.

```
-- Columns common to all types.
create table items (
  item_id integer primary key,
  item_type varchar(10) not null
    check (item_type in 'doll', 'car', 'boat'),

  -- This constraint lets the pair of columns be the target of a foreign key reference.
  unique (item_id, item_type),

  item_date date not null default current_date,
  item_source varchar(25) not null
);

-- Columns unique to dolls. I'd assume that "size" means one thing when you're
-- talking about dolls, and something slightly different when you're talking
-- about boats.
create table dolls (
  item_id integer primary key,
  item_type varchar(10) not null default 'doll'
    check(item_type = 'doll'),
  foreign key (item_id, item_type) references items (item_id, item_type),
  doll_size integer not null 
    check(doll_size between 1 and 20),
  doll_material varchar(25) not null  -- In production, probably references a table 
                                      -- of valid doll materials.
);
```

The column dolls.item_type, along with its CHECK constraint and the foreign key reference, guarantees that

- every row in "dolls" has a matching row in "items", and
- that matching row is *also* about dolls. (Not about boats or cars.)

Tables for boats and cars are similar.

If you have to implement this in MySQL, you'll have to replace the CHECK constraints, because MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints. In some cases, you can replace them with a foreign key reference to a tiny table. In other cases, you might have to write a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

What I am trying to achieve is called *Polymorphic Association*. This can be accomplished by creating a super table to store all possible columns and using a second and third table to constrain foreign keys to primary keys.

Its explained in detail [here](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql)